# How to set/modify connection pool from azure web app to azure sql database - Slow App Issue

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have performance issue with my .NET app hosted on an azure web app, connecting to Azure SQL DB with a custom connection string.
The more there are users, the more the app is slow. Therefore I am wondering if there are some improvements to perform at connection pool level.

How to check the pool size currently set ? How to detect sql issues when handling requests from different users ? And how to set pool size ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to [SQL Database resource limits for Azure SQL Database server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server).

The more there are users, the more the app is slow, one of the most important reason is  database resource limits are reached.

**Compute (DTUs and eDTUs / vCores)**

When database compute utilization (measured by DTUs and eDTUs, or vCores) becomes high, query latency increases and can even time out.

**Storage**

When database space used reaches the max size limit, database inserts and updates that increase the data size fail and clients receive an error message. Database SELECTS and DELETES continue to succeed.

**Sessions and workers (requests)**

The maximum number of sessions and workers are determined by the service tier and compute size (DTUs and eDTUs). New requests are rejected when session or worker limits are reached, and clients receive an error message. While the number of connections available can be controlled by the application, the number of concurrent workers is often harder to estimate and control. This is especially true during peak load periods when database resource limits are reached and workers pile up due to longer running queries.

Fore details, please reference: [What happens when database resource limits are reached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server#what-happens-when-database-resource-limits-are-reached).

If you Azure SQL DB is single database, you can reference these documents:

1. [Azure SQL Database vCore-based purchasing model limits for a single database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases).
2. [Resource limits for single databases using the DTU-based purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases).

Choose the most appropriate service tier.

About the performance issue, you also can use the  [Monitoring and performance tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview). It will help troubleshoot performance issue and  improve the performance.

Hope this helps.